# Show values instead of getter/setter functions in Firefox DevTools variable view

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When inspecting a JavaScript object, that uses getter/setter functions for properties (defined with [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)) in the Firefox [DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools) variables view, it shows the defined getter and setter functions for this particular property:

[image]

Is there any way to show the actual content instead of the functions in this view?

Edit: as nils commented, viewing the actual content means technically invoking the getter.

Comment: I would love an answer to this question as well! (Assuming by actual content you mean invoking the getters to get the current value).

Comment: If the act of observing ie. invoking the getter changes the state of the code (like a get counter or something), what is expected of the debugger?

Comment: @Brian the question is: how the Chrome developer tool achieve this behaviour?

Comment: The Chrome DevTools display the value but sometimes it's not the current one and sometimes they call the getter. Simple example: Add `obj.counter` as watch expression for `var obj = {i:0, get counter() { return this.i++; }}` and then switch between the panels. You'll see the value increasing. And when `obj.counter` is executed via the command line, the value is not updated within the watch expression.

Comment: Btw. Firebug always displays the current value, but therefore calls the getter several times, which increases the value. See http://superuser.com/a/1122160/324429.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Firefox 65 this is possible to invoke a getter via a button next to it within the logged object.

[image: Button to invoke a getter]

This was implemented in [bug 820878](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820878) resp. [issue 6140 on GitHub](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/6140).

In versions prior to Firefox 65 you could output the getter's return value by simply calling it directly via the command line.

Comment: According to the last comment there the issue was just [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/devtools-html/devtools-core/issues/510).

Comment: The issue has been moved again - now at https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/6140

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Thank you for the hint! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is to use this workaround - instead of logging the object:

```
console.log(objectVar)
```

You can assign the current state into an empty object and then log it:

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, objectVar)) // works on all browsers
// OR
console.log({...objectVar}) // es6 only
```

---

Sidenote: writing this gets tedious fast so if you use a code editor (Atom/VScode) then you can [add this as a snippet](https://paul.copplest.one/gists/vscode-snippets.html)

Here is an example snippet where you can just type 'l' then press tab:

```
'.source.js':
  'console.log object':
    'prefix': 'l'
    'body': "console.log('${1:variable}', Object.assign({}, ${1:variable}))"
```

OR for ES6:

```
'.source.js':
      'console.log object':
        'prefix': 'l'
        'body': "console.log('${1:variable}', {...${1:variable}})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will display incorrectly object properties gathered from for example API, but values created instantly in context are shown properly.
I found a workaround with lodash library (https://lodash.com/)
Or eventually it is possible to do it with another js framework, which is able to fully clone object.

```
  console.dir(_.cloneDeep(objectToShowInConsole));
```